# What are the six characters on this seal? (Characters identified: 漢高皇帝後裔)

Tags: characters, character-identification, seal

[image]

What are the characters on this seal? The middle two seem to be 皇帝, but I can't make out the other four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edited, according to info provided by droooze.

the recognised character in sequence:

```
５３１
６４２
```

character ５：後 (u+5f8c)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=後](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BE%8C)

character ６：裔 (u+88d4)

http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%A3%94

character ３：皇 (u+7687)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=皇](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%9A%87)

character ４：帝 (u+5e1d)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=帝](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B8%9D)

character １, the left component is 水 (u+6c34), the left one, wait :)

edited. with help from droooze, this one should be 漢 (u+6f22)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=漢](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%BC%A2)

character ２, this one would be 亙 (u+4e99)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=亙](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BA%99)

so, it would be read as "漢亙皇帝後裔", roughly "the descendent of emperor '漢亙帝'"

have fun :)

Comment: Character 5 is 漢 I think

Comment: @droooze yes, you got it :) any idea about character 6? imo, i wonder if it's a chinese character :)

Comment: Best guess at the moment is 亘, as abbreviation of 漢桓帝. Maybe this is a badly made seal on a TV show haha

Comment: 亘, great, a best guess :) btw, i think that, an emperor's seal should be made by gold, or jade. so, may we say that it's a counterfeit, according to the photo :)

Comment: What does 汉桓帝 have to do with 后齐（北齐）? According to google they are separated by over 400 years.

Comment: well, i doubt that this seal is a counterfeit :(

Comment: The second character is 裔, written in 說文傳抄古文字 style. See http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=3242. The seal should say "The Descendants of Emperor Huan of Han" (pending on correctness of the guess 桓).

Comment: That makes more sense, saw it in a store, so yeah likely fake.

Comment: 裔, yeah, it's more likely, thanks droooze :)

Comment: Solved the lower right character!

Comment: @droooze, “高”? interesting, any comparison available?

Comment: http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/char?fontcode=82.F0AD

Comment: 漢高祖 > "漢高皇帝" https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=gb&did=4035

Comment: @droooze, i’m only half convinced. anyway, it’s better than “亘”, semantically.

Comment: I know what happened to this character (see http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/chuanchao?kaiOrder=1957 for more examples). This is later corrupted shape, it originally referred to 郭 (http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2420) in bronze inscription, people later misread it as 高.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link, see http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=21597 - original shape of 郭