# What is the missing character on the seal?

Tags: character-identification, seal

跟進[此問題](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31166/what-are-the-six-characters-on-this-seal)，題中之印

[image]

共收六字，其中五字無疑，作爲

## <kbd>後皇漢
裔帝Ｘ</kbd>

Ｘ是何字，解之有難。僅看字形，個人釋之爲「亘」，而@水巷孑蠻釋之爲「亙」，因漢朝既無「亘帝」也無「亙帝」，二解都有問題。

先說說「亘」與「亙」二字的字源。二者在秦漢之後已經就被混淆了，甚至到今世多釋之爲繁簡或異體關係，非也。

> 「亘」字本義是環繞、迴旋，很可能跟「還」、「漩」等類似的詞有同源關係，但初期竝無「亘」字而以「回」字當之，然後世「亘」字从「回」字分化。「回」是象形字，像迴旋流水，本義今作「洄」。
>
> ## <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)903
> [合集34165](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=34165&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>楚
> [簡](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E7%AE%80%E7%89%8D)
> [image]
> [新](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)3.294</kbd>
> 　<kbd>秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [睡](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9D%A1%E8%99%8E%E5%9C%B0%E7%A7%A6%E7%AE%80)ㆍ[秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)148</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> 在「回」字上或重複「回」字、或加幾筆橫畫，迺成「亘」。例：
>
> ## <kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 史墻盤「」
> [集成10175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10175&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 虢季子白盤「」
> [集成10173](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10173&jgwfl=)</kbd>
>
> 今「亘」字是傳承以「回」字上加兩筆橫畫竝無重複的結構，其中「回」部件後來變成了「日」形：
>
> ## <kbd>篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> 「亙」字來源完全不同。「亙」迺「恆」，「㮓」二者的初文，二者是以「亙」上加義符而分化出來的字。「亙」也是象形字，像半月在天地之間。
>
> ## <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)199.3
> [合集14764](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=14764&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 亙鼎
> [集成2380](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2380&jgwfl=)</kbd>　<kbd>現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

在今世收集的通用字沒有从「亘」作爲義符的字，而有以「亘」（須緣切）當聲符的字，例如「桓」、「宣」等（「恆」類似以胡登切「亙」部件作爲聲符的字，不以俗體「恒」等當之，免得迷惑）。

漢代無「亘帝」、「亙帝」，但確有

- 漢文帝　劉**恆**
- 漢**宣**帝　劉病已
- 漢**桓**帝　劉志

印璽如果不是完全瞎製的一個玩具，我認爲Ｘ是上面粗體三者其中的一位假借字。查了劉煇《古文字通假字典》（[722頁](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/kangxi/pic.php?f=tjzzd&p=722)）之後，個人還是覺得Ｘ是「亘」字。

> ### 亘
>
> 4885（元心 xuan）讀為桓（元匣 huan），叠韻
>
> 岣嶁碑：＂唯王二年六月丁酉，承嗣越臣憲亘朱句。＂曹錦炎《岣嶁碑研究》云＂憲亘＂即＂憲桓＂，乃＂朱句＂自諡之詞。又馬王堆帛書《春秋事話ㆍ齊桓公與蔡夫人乘舟章》：＂齊亘公與蔡夫人乘周（舟），夫人湯（蕩）周，禁之，不可，怒而歸之......亘公帀（師）以侵蔡，蔡人遂潰。＂＂亘公＂即＂桓公＂，《左傳ㆍ僖公三年》曾記此事，＂齊亘公＂作＂齊侯＂，魯僖公三年即齊桓公二十九年。

但是，我竝沒搜到有＂漢Ｘ帝＂而以Ｘ作爲通假字的記錄；證據不夠堅强，不可判斷在此印中Ｘ到底是甚麽字。

讀者如何？

Comment: 欲辨明此印何不諮詢原題主印璽之出處？

Comment: @TooskyHierot StackExchange Rules: `Don’t post an answer as a question. If you have a question on a current question, please post a separate question and link it.` (Paraphrased, forgot where I read that)

Comment: You can comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

> 跟進此問題，題中之印

圖略

> Ｘ是何字，解之有難。僅看字形，個人釋之爲「亘」，而@水巷孑蠻釋之爲「亙」，因漢朝既無「亘帝」也無「亙帝」，二解都有問題。

nice try, just some corners of vernacular chinese. practise more, you can master the writing of literary chinese :)

may i suggest:

緣前題雖解．而一疑尚存．固起此問求真

斯印存六字．其五已釋．惟漢後皇前之刻．亘乎．亙乎．眾說紛紜．未審孰是孰非．再者．漢世無亘．亙之諡．益添困惑

back to basic, a seal is for **authentication**, to make a stamping that other can recognised the stamped document as authentic, from a individual, or an entity.

the seal in question just declare "descendent of a particular emperor of 漢 dynasty".

any mr 劉 can make such claim, so?

next, the text "漢ｘ皇帝後裔" is redundant & ugly. "漢室宗親"; 4 characters are enough for this purpose.

last, 亙 (u+4e99) is suggested, well, because the 漢語多功能字庫 do not has 亘 (u+4e98)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=亘](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BA%98)

and, the 國語辭典 claimed 亘 (u+4e98) as variant of 亙 (u+4e99)

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000070331

i need to read more, before making any sound judgement :(

last, relax, treat it as a "hello kitty stamp" :)

what i want to say is, hello kitty is based on a cat, it does not have a line to represent a mouth, and, it's "tail" is a circle only.

Comment: yes, don't "waste" too much efforts on this one. have fun :)

Comment: Well I initially thought it was a badly made seal on a TV show. Just thought it may have had an alternative interpretation :)

Comment: sound interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

It could simply be 室 as in 漢室 (Han dynasty)

[「室」字的起源《说文解字》](https://zidian.wenku1.com/%E5%AE%A4/qiyuan.shtml)

"漢室皇帝後裔" (Han Dynasty emperor descendant) make a lot of sense

[image]